# What sectors would be most affected positively or negatively by Trump´s trade agreement renegotiations?

Tags: international-trade, political-economy, regulation

One of Trump´s stated policies is that he will renegotiate the trade agreements with China and the Canada and México (NAFTA). This renegotiation might go well in which maybe the US gets freer access to markets in these countries, or it might just turn into protectionism and tariff increase. 
Which industries in the US (manufacturing, industrial, extractive, construction, services, etc) does trade theory suggest would be most affected (either positively or negatively) by an general move towards protectionism and tariffs by the US?

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense.